# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I already installed my App to 2 clients laptop. The application works properly on the one laptop while on the one laptop, there's an error and it says:

> Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click
>   continue. The application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>   "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered"

I check his laptop. it is 64 bit. what can i do?

Comment: What is the target platform for your project? If it's Any CPU, is the Prefer 32-bit box checked. Does the user have Office installed?  If so, which version?

Comment: "what can i do?  --> You could have reviewed the existing  answers listed under **Questions that may already have your answer** when you created your question and explained to us what you tried that did not work.  There is also the **Related** question list on the right side of this page that you could review.  What makes you think that your case is special and warrants a new question for a problem that has been discussed many times in the past?

Answer (score 1):

You Need to install this Component..

- The [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734).